# Can Dirichlet and multinomial distributions be defined from their univariate distributions this way?

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

For Dirichlet distribution:

- $X := [x_1, \cdots, x_K] \in  [0,1]^K$, $x_i \sim {\rm beta}(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ and $\sum x_i = 1$. Can we say the distribution of $X$ is a Dirichlet distribution?
- If no, will adding $\sum_{i=1}^K \beta_i = (K-1) \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i$ work?
- Or will replace $\sum x_i = 1$ with $\sum_{i=1}^K \beta_i = (K-1) \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i$ work?

For multinomial distribution:

- $X := [x_1, \cdots, x_K] \in  \{0,1, \dots, n\}^K$, $x_i \sim {\rm binomial}(p_i)$ and $\sum x_i = n$ for some constant natural number $n$. Can we say the distribution of $X$ is a multinomial distribution?
- If no,  will adding $\sum_{i=1}^K p_i = 1$ work?
- Or will replace $\sum x_i = n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^K p_i = 1$ work?

Comment: ok. @gung   $ $ $ $

Comment: Multinomial is sampling with replacement, so each $x_i$ can range up to $n$.

Comment: Isn't that already implied by $\sum_i x_i = n$? @NeilG

Comment: @Tim: you wrote $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, but it should be $\{0,1,…,n\}$.